# How can i change firstname and lastname on billing address with a value from another field

Tags: magento2, checkout, billing-address, address

I've added a new field(fullname ) on the checkout billing address using a plugin on `Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor`, and I also hide the `firstname` and `lastname`.
Now I want to populate the first and last name with the value from full name ( split the value where we have empty space)
My problem is that I don't know how to do that.
I've tried in my abstract js `Custom_Checkout/js/checkout/abstract` to assign the value like this :

```
setFirstLastNameFromFullName : function(){
    console.log(quote)
    var fullValue = this.value();
    var address = quote.billingAddress();
    address.firstname = fullValue.substr(0,fullValue.indexOf(' '));
    address.lastname = fullValue.substr(0,fullValue.indexOf(' ')+1);
},
```

but is not working. Code from the plugin:

```
    if (isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
        ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children']
    )) {
        $paymentList = &$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
        ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'];

        foreach ($paymentList as $key => $payment) {

            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$key]['children']['form-fields']['children']
            ['city_id']['sortOrder'] = 110;

            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$key]['children']['form-fields']['children']
            ['firstname']['visible'] = false;

            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$key]['children']['form-fields']['children']
            ['lastname']['visible'] = false;

            if (isset($payment['component']) AND $payment['component'] === 'Magento_Checkout/js/view/billing-address') {
                $billingConfiguration = &$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$key]['children']['form-fields']['children'];

                $billingConfiguration = $this->setFullName($billingConfiguration, 'billingAddress');
            }
        }
    }

    return $jsLayout;
}

/**
 * Set "Full Name"
 * @param array $shippingConfiguration
 * @return array
 */
private function setFullName(array  $addressConfiguration, $scope){

    $addressConfiguration['full_name'] = [
        'component' => 'CUstom_Checkout/js/checkout/abstract',
        'config' => [
            'customScope' => $scope.'.full_name',
            'template' => 'ui/form/field',
            'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input',
            'options' => [],
            'id' => 'full-name'
        ],
        'dataScope' => $scope.'.full_name',
        'label' => __('First and Last Name'),
        'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
        'visible' => true,
        'validation' => [
            'required-entry' => true,
            'validate-firstlast-name' => true
        ],
        'sortOrder' => 0,
        'id' => 'full-name',
    ];

    $addressConfiguration = $this->makeTrackableFirstLastName($addressConfiguration);

    return $addressConfiguration;
}

private function makeTrackableFirstLastName(array  $addressConfiguration){
    $addressConfiguration['firstname']['tracks']['value'] = true;
    $addressConfiguration['lastname']['tracks']['value'] = true;

    return $addressConfiguration;
}
```

Does anyone know how can i do this?